# Combine https an http URL in the facebook "like" count

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I had a certain amount of likes for my website using the facebook code snippet:

```
www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http://www.mywebsite.com
```

Now that I have switched the whole website to https for the first time, the total count indicates 0 instead of the previous amount of likes I had when the site was based on http

Is there a way to implement the facebook like button so that it combines both likes for the http and the https version of the website?

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Only by setting the `og:url` value to either the HTTP _or_ HTTPS version for _both_ versions. (And no automatic redirects to the “other” version then, because that would make the FB scraper detect a redirect loop. If you have to redirect, then implement an exemption for the scraper.)

Comment: I am using the iframe "like" code snippet which looks like this    <iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href= , therefore if I use og:url, what should I put in the href parameter? Thanks

Comment: Doesn’t matter which one you put as `href`.

Comment: I have a website, bachecubano.com where in the http version it has 6645 likes, but in the https version only 791. Why facebook do this?